# Why function inside react component is not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, components, speech-recognition

I have a react component where I am using speech recognition to detect speech to text,I have initialize recognition functions inside the component but for some reason they are giving errors. Can someone help me fixing it?

```
const speechRecognition = window.speechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
const recognition=new speechRecognition()


class Editor extends Component {
   
state = {
        lang: "cpp17",
        mode: "clike",
        value: `
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x=10;
    cin>>x;
    cout<<x;
}
        `,
    };
    url="https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.jdoodle.com/v1/execute"
    recognition.onstart=()=>function()
{
    console.log("speak now")
}
recognition.onresult=()=>function(event){
    const current=event.resultIndex;
    const transcript=event.results[current][0].transcript;
    this.setState({value:this.state.value+transcript})
}
```

both the `recognition.onstart` and `recognition.onresult` functions are giving syntax error.How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

callback function:

```
() => {}
```

is already a kind of function - you do not need to add the `function` keyword with it.

You can just put your functional logic inside the `{}` like this:

```
recognition.onstart = () => {
    console.log("speak now")
}
recognition.onresult = () => {
    const current=event.resultIndex;
    const transcript=event.results[current][0].transcript;
    this.setState({value:this.state.value+transcript})
}
```

Comment: problem is with the dot after recognition,as vscode is suggesting

Comment: okay, weird, can you post the exact error message?